# Cleric Domain Granted Powers

Tags: pathfinder-1e, cleric, domains

What are granted power in clerics' domain?
For example out of the core rulebook for travel:

> Granted Powers: You are an explorer and find
>   enlightenment in the simple joy of travel, be it by foot or
>   conveyance or magic. Increase your base speed by 10 feet.

Is that a passive effect that is always active?
Secondly there are two powers in each domain section like this for travel:

> Agile Feet (Su): As a free action, you can gain increased
>   mobility for 1 round. For the next round, you ignore all
>   difficult terrain and do not take any penalties for moving
>   through it. You can use this ability a number of times per
>   day equal to 3 + your Wisdom modifier.
>
> Dimensional Hop (Sp): At 8th level, you can teleport up
>   to 10 feet per cleric level per day as a move action. This
>   teleportation must be used in 5-foot increments and such
>   movement does not provoke attacks of opportunity. You
>   must have line of sight to your destination to use this
>   ability. You can bring other willing creatures with you,
>   but you must expend an equal amount of distance for each
>   creature brought.

Do these count towards domain spells or are those independent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Agile feet* and *dimensional hop* are the powers granted by the travel domain; notice the heading above them saying **Granted Powers**.

The 10-ft. movement speed increase isn’t technically a “granted power,” but rather just a little something extra for choosing this domain. These extras don’t really have a name, that I’m aware of, but a few domains have them. For another example, the animal domain adds Knowledge (nature) to the cleric class skill list. These are just permanent changes to your character that you get for having the domain.

None of these interact with any of your spells, domain or otherwise. They do not take up spell slots. Instead, they each have their own notation of their resource usage: the 10-ft. movement bonus is permanent, *agile feet* is usable (3+Wis) times per day, and *dimensional hop* allows a total of 10 feet per level worth of teleportation, spread out amont however many such hops you want to make (each hop being a teleport of some multiple of 5 feet).

Answer (score 4):

### None of those powers are spells

The first, the base speed improvement, is permanent. As stated, if you are a cleric of the Travel Domain, your base speed is 10 feet higher than what you'd normally have (plus any other bonuses from race, spells...)

The next two are powers you can employ within the restrictions specified. Unrelated to spells. In the first case, you use a free action up to 3+Wis mod/day, in the second you use a move actionup to your level/day.

As said, these powers are completely independent from spells. First permanent, next two "usable".